# Science Fiction Novel with the Word Diamond in the Title

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is a book that is probably more than 20 years old. It would be pre-2000 (most likely).

It has diamond in the title (I believe). I also think of the word satellite or space station.

It has two political groups that are against each other or at least at odds with each other.

There is an arranged marriage.

The girl that is sent to be married has an operation that covers her clitoris with some type of plastic or material that keeps her from enjoying certain adult activities.

The family that she is married into removes this so that her and her husband can bond better. He is young. They are both young. Perhaps 17 to 19.

That's about all that I remember. Adult themes for sure. Political.

They end up developing feelings for each other. There's a really adult scene with oral sex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that’s probably [*City of Diamond*](http://www.dorisegan.com/works/novels/city-of-diamond-reviews/) by Doris Egan (who went on to be a TV producer on *House* rather then continuing her writing career). It was first published in 1996 under the pseudonym Jane Emerson.

> Adrian Mercati is thrown into the role of Protector of the City of
>   Diamond, one of the Three Cities vast interstellar spaceships with
>   whole religious cultures based on a murky past and an alien
>   intervention. Not that he doesn’t want the job, and not that he’s not
>   the man for it, but at twenty, he’s a tad on the young side. He
>   immediately makes arrangements for a political marriage to Iolanthe of
>   the City of Opal, a seventeen-year-old who makes him seem worldly and
>   wise.